# How to rotate car.glb wheels using useGLTF()

Tags: reactjs, blender, react-three-fiber, gltf

I wanna rotate wheels of the car model. Here I can't upload model cause of the size.
This is the car model : [Path](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E8J81xYI5teuF_C8zuZ2PQQ1CrWkRx3z/view?usp=sharing)

This is my code in live without car model : [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-greider-7s6mmg?file=/src/Car.js)

I use this but not working:

```
useFrame((state, delta) => {
        let t = state.clock.getElapsedTime();
        c.scene.children[13].rotateX(t*2);
        c.scene.children[14].rotateX(t*2);
    });
```